# Parse geo-queries always empty

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

Im currently trying to get Parse's geo-query system to work. On my data browser, I have an installation with a key "location" of type geo-point that has a geo-point with latitude 30.27263636013176 and longitude -97.75766807716373 set in it.

However, if I try to query with the following code, I always get "results":[].

```
curl -X GET \ 
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: myAppKey" \ 
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: myAPIKey" \ 
-G \ --data-urlencode 'limit=10' \
--data-urlencode 'where={
"location": {
  "$nearSphere": {
    "__type": "GeoPoint",
    "latitude": 30,
    "longitude": -97
  }
}
}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/PlaceObject
```

Note that the query is running successfully; there are no errors. The problem is the installation I have should come up.

If I change the latitude and longitude in the query to exactly the latitude and longitude shown in the data browser, I still get empty results. What is the reason for this? Is it not possible to query for device installations near a point?

Answer (score 2):

The `Installation` class can't be queried from the client, for good reason. Too much sensitive information is stored in the `Installation` class to allow querying from a client.

Either move the `location` property to another class you can query, or query it in a Cloud Function.

You can query it in Cloud Code if you use `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();`, though I strongly recommend using a different class to store the `location`.

Comment: So is there a way to move the location property to another class but keep that information connected to individual installations? Ideally I would like to be able to say, send a push notification to all devices near some location

Comment: Also I am not sure I understand what you mean that the installation class can't be queried. I can set queries for as many custom tags in an installation as I want, and they work. I can set queries for channels in the installation class, and they work. This is the only column in the installations that doesn't seem to query correctly.

Comment: Can you confirm that you only have one column of type GeoPoint in your Installation class?

Comment: user3684980 - to answer your question above, you could make another table and use the objectId or the installationId as a foreign key.  I'm actually trying to do the same thing as you seem to be though, so am watching this answer with interest.  When I try to use Cloud Code I'm getting an "Error 102 $nearSphere: invalid geopoint object" which led me to attempt what you are asking about in your OP.

Comment: @Jason
I also run into similar issue. I was wondering if you guys have solved this?

Comment: For that project I believe I put the location in a new class, and then set a cloud code method for after a row was changed in the installation object to update the relevant row in the new class.

Answer (score 0):

Should the url be `https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Installation` instead of `https://api.parse.com/1/classes/PlaceObject` ?