# Parse CloudCode invalid geopoint object

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using the JavaScript SDK in Parse Cloud Code, attempting to write a query that filters off of a GeoPoint.  I keep getting the error:

```
{"code":141,"error":" Error: 102 $nearSphere: invalid geopoint object"}
```

My code looks like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("findPeopleNearby", function (request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
if (request.params.latitude && request.params.longitude) {
    var point = new Parse.GeoPoint({ latitude: request.params.latitude, longitude: request.params.longitude });
    console.log('would query off of GeoPoint: ' + JSON.stringify(point));

    var places = Parse.Object.extend("UserLocation");
    var placesQuery = new Parse.Query(places);
    placesQuery.near("location", point);

    placesQuery.find({
        success: function (results)
        {
            console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " rows.");
            response.success();
        },
        error: function (error)
        {
            response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
}});
```

I know that the data in the table is okay, because I can issue a curl command with success:

```
curl -X GET -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxx" -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: yyyy" -G --data-urlencode 'limit=5' --data-urlencode 'where={ "location": { "$nearSphere": { "__type": "GeoPoint", "latitude": 37.33521504  , "longitude": -122.03254905 }, "$maxDistanceInMiles":10.0 } }'  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/UserLocation
```

I originally had the location property on the Installation table (which is where I would prefer it to be), but I saw [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24316477/519030) and thought that I would try it in its own object, but that did not seem to make a difference.

As an aside, if I can get this query to work, my next attempt would be to join the Installation object using a parent pointer.  I hope/assume that that would work if I can understand what is causing this error.

Thanks

EDIT console output

```
would query off of GeoPoint: {"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":"37.33521504","longitude":"-122.03254905"}
```

Comment: How does the console log look for point?

Comment: My guess is that the lat/long are not numbers and therefore the Parse.GeoPoint is invalid, really need to see the output of that first `console.log` of the `point`.

Comment: arrrgh, I bet that's it.  I'll try tonight.  Updated question.  Thanks a thousand.

Comment: @Fosco might I suggest that the `Parse.GeoPoint` constructor attempt to do a `parseFloat()` on the input when it isn't a number in the next version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timothy's suspicions were correct.  The inputs were strings and not floats.  Casting the inputs solves the error and, in fact, querying to "join" the installation object then works fine as well.  A silly error, but hopefully now anyone Googling it will find a result to point them in the right direction.

Long version for reference:

```
        var lat, lng;

    if (typeof request.params.latitude === "number") {
        lat = request.params.latitude;
    }
    else {
        lat = parseFloat(request.params.latitude);
        // this could return NaN
    }

    if (typeof request.params.longitude === "number") {
        lng = request.params.longitude;
    }
    else {
        lng = parseFloat(request.params.longitude);
    }

    var point = new Parse.GeoPoint({ latitude: lat, longitude: lng });
```