# Parse push notification shows empty geo-queries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

This is similar to but it's a continuation to [Parse geo-queries always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314681/parse-geo-queries-always-empty)

I have device installations working correctly, and i've created a customized class "test_users" that contains the location data. each instance in the "Installation" class holds a pointer to the "test_users" instance, with column name "test" below** you can see below, and when I clicked on the pointer value, it will go to that "test_user" instance.
[image: Installation class]

and "test_users" class
[image: test_users class]

I have the following javascript code to Query the channel and location to send push notification:

```
$http({
        "url": "https://api.parse.com/1/push",
        "method": "POST",
        "data": {
            "data": { "alert": "test!! ", 
                                "sound": "beep.caf", 
                                "badge": "Increment",  
                                "uid":user_uid, 
                                "date":date, 
                                "time":time
            },
            "where": {
                "channel": category,
                "test": {
                "$inQuery": {
                  "location": {
                    "$nearSphere": {
                      "__type": "GeoPoint",
                      "latitude": 37.7150 ,
                      "longitude": -117.1625
                    },
                    "$maxDistanceInMiles": 20
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        },
        "headers": {
            "X-Parse-Application-Id": "######",
            "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "#######",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "params": 
        {
            "uid" : user_uid,
            "date": date,
            "time": time
        }
    });
```

However, no push notification is created, and when i check the analytics, i see this  [image]

Any thoughts on where I made the query mistake? or anything wrong with "test_users" class? **Update: On a different experiment, I also created a _User class just like the parse.com push notification doc did (and have "Installation" instance storing a pointer to the _User instance), and got same empty geo-query result.**

Comment: Anybody has any clues?